# Can't start mysql on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql, mariadb

A query which was killed was still running. So I stopped the server and tried to start it back up. But now it refuses to start up. Here is the error: `Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

Output of `systemctl status mysql.service`:

```
● mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-05-28 15:52:16 IST; 15s ago
Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 16718 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/mysql stop (code=killed, signal=TERM)
Process: 27200 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Tasks: 28
Memory: 28.9G
CPU: 32.735s
```

I'm running MariaDB 10.

Answer (score 0):

I found the `pid` for `mysqld` and issued a `kill -9` and then started mysql. It worked.